# Error - Input string was not in a correct format after publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, model-view-controller, form-data

I get an error - Input string was not in a correct format. In debug all works as it supposed to, this code was working fine months before just of today thought to stop working with this error

> ExceptionMessage: "Input string was not in a correct format."
>
> ExceptionType: "System.FormatException"
>
> #### StackTrace:
>
> System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>
> at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
>
> at App.Controllers.DataTableController.Post_Edit()
>   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
>   ↵   at
>
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_2.b__2(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
>   ↵   at
>
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Form data to API:

[image: e1]

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/datatable/post_edit")]
public IHttpActionResult Post_Edit()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["id"]);
    int plan = 0;
    if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["plan"] != "") {
        plan = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["plan"]);
    }
    var worker_id = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["worker_id"]);
    var project = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["project"]);
    var valvalue = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["valvalue"]);
    var kof = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["kof"]);
    var week = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["week"]);
    var company = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["company"]);
    var db_company = db.apsk_company.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == company).company;
    var add_to = Convert.ToDateTime(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["add_to"]);
    double work_hours = Convert.ToDouble(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["value"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var user = db.apsk_users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.username == User.Identity.Name);
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Which of those calls to `Convert.ToInt32` is failing? (Hopefully your stack trace has line numbers, or you can add logging to find out...)

Comment: Could any of those `Int32` values have grown beyond the bounds of the `Int32` range?

Comment: The code is prone to parsing errors. All those `Convert.ToXXX` calls are just `int.Parse`, `double.Parse` calls. All of those calls except one don't specify a CultureInfo so they use the current culture to parse the strings. If that locale doesn't match the data, there will be an error. On the other hand, if the data is wrong, eg the `week` parameter contains `moo`, you'd get a parsing exception anyway

Comment: @AdamV - no they can't all numers are small.

Comment: In any case, this code isn't good MVC code. All those parameters should appear as action parameters. There's no reason *at all* to use `HttpContext.Current.Request`. This makes testing a lot harder than it needs to be. The action parameters could be strongly typed too, letting MVC itself perform the deserialization.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - now it's abit changed code because I tried to maybe it will start working. In first it wast `Int32.parse` for plan and `double.Parse` for work_hours but none of those work.

Comment: @xNaii one of them isn't a valid integer though. That's what the error says - one of those strings can't be parsed. What is the *actual* request?

Comment: @xNaii if you pas "moo" to `int.Parse` it won't work, no matter how you change the code. What is the *actual* string that causes the problem? Did you try debugging this code? Where did it stop?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no texts in there only numbers and one date

Comment: @JonSkeet there is no trace numbers :(

Comment: @xNaii they are *all* text, which is why you need to call `Convert.` HTTP requests contain text only. One of them can't be parsed. When that happens, the debugger stops at the line that threw the exception. What line was it and what did the parameter contain? Split the code in different read/parse lines at least, so you can easily inspect the value that caused the exception.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos for curriosity - why this code works localy - localhost and after  publishing to server it gets error with same data from same database?

Comment: @xNaii because your machine has a different locale than the server. Just like different locales have different date formats, they may have different decimal formats too. Is `12/13/2019` a valid date or not? In most of Europe, it is. In the US, it isn't. In Russia, it would be `12.13.2019` I think

Comment: `with same data from same database` it's not the same data. Wherever that data came, it was posted as a *string* to the service. The problem may have been caused by whatever formatted the numbers and made the HTTP call.